# Loop that generates 10 random number in the range 20-50 and displays it

Tags: c#

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        // Question #3 answer

        int number;
        int min=20,max=50;
        Random RandomNumber = new Random();

        for ( number= 20; number<=50; number++)

            RandomNumber.Next(20, 50);

        Console.WriteLine (number);                                                                 
    }    
}
```

Comment: I want to know if the above code is correct. can someone help me out?

Comment: Please reformat the code and add some explanation what do you want.

Comment: Just run it.  If you want to test it online, there are online code demo sites like dotnetfiddle.  If you don't actually have a specific question about its correctness, your question off-topic here.

Comment: Add `Console.ReadKey();`  after your `Console.WriteLine(number);` and see what your output is. From there, add a breakpoint and figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: `picks = Enumerable.Range(20, 30).OrderBy( x => RNG.Next()).Take(10).ToArray()`

Comment: @Plutonix Post it as an asnwer so that we can downvote it :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want:

```
    int min=20,max=50;
    Random RandomNumber = new Random();

    for (var count = 0; count<10; count++)
        Console.WriteLine(RandomNumber.Next(min, max));
```

The for loop runs 10 iterations, and each iteration `Console.WriteLine()`'s a new random number between `min` and `max`.

Comment: Thank you very much i knew i was close to getting it

Comment: This won't compile because `count` is not defined. Also, actually explain what your answer does.

Comment: I had to delcare a variable of type int and name it count